# how to delete remember me cookie in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, remember-me

I was wondering how to the remove the remember me cookie when using spring remember me services.
I am using the default remember me cookie name 
I came across the following documentation in spring to delete the JSESSION.

```
    <http>
      <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>
```

But is it possible to do something like below to delete the remember me cookie as well

I don't have a logout controller and i have the following configuration in the spring xml.

```
  <http use-expressions="true">
    <!-- Authentication policy -->
    <form-login login-page="/signin" login-processing-url="/signin/authenticate" authentication-failure-url="/signin?param.error=bad_credentials" />
    <logout logout-url="/signout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
            ....................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to manually delete the remember-me cookie. The `AbstractRememberMeServices` implements the `LogoutHandler` interface, so it will receive a call-back from the `LogoutFilter`, and makes sure the remember-me cookie is cancelled on logout.

Comment: I think you are right...i saw in the code that calls cancel cookie on logout event. SO that might will invalidate the remember me cookie because I came across a method called cancel cookie.

Comment: It's definitely the case, and also easy to check by allowing debug level loging for the `AbstractRememberMeServices`.